# Update variable outside callback

Tags: java, asynccallback

I'm using facebook SDK for Android. I have a request which has a callback from where I get the response. I have to execute the request a variable number of times depending on the response I get from the request. I'm trying to use a global variable outside the callback function and update it using the response but it's not working. Here is how I'm taclkling it.

The global variable:

```
int dataLength = -1;
```

To continually execute the request:

```
while (dataLength == -1){
getComments("20");
}
```

The issue is that it is as if the dataLength is never being updated though it should be updated on the very first call

The request and callback function:

```
public void getComments(String offset){
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/inbox",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                        dataLength = graphResponse.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data").length;
                    }
                });
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("limit", "20");
parameters.putString("offset", offset);
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your while-loop and your asynchronous callback are running in separate threads, so without some sort of synchronization, there is no guarantee that values of `dataLength` written in one thread will be read in the other. (See ["Memory Consistency Errors" in the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).)

The simplest fix for that problem is to tack on the `volatile` keyword:

```
private volatile int dataLength = -1;
```

This ensures that each read of `dataLength` will retrieve the latest-written value.

Comment: @user1774937: I guess you had more than one problem, then. Well, best of luck with the rest of them. :-)

Comment: the only issue i have is that the loop is running infinitely :/

Comment: You're only observing one problematic behavior, but there are apparently multiple underlying bugs, in that fixing one of the bugs did not fix the behavior.